# Is there a way to use next-i18next without Next.js internationalized routing?

Tags: internationalization, next.js, react-i18next, next-i18next

I'm using `next-i18next` package in couple of projects already and it works great.

In my current project I need to integrate i18n, but this time only with cookie support, without internationalized routing and I wonder if I can achieve that with this package or I should go back to `react-i18next` and `i18next`

Sample:

```
// No cookie or EN cookie
https://app.example.com shows EN version

// Cookie `next-i18n-lang` set to specific language (IT, DE, etc)
https://app.example.com shows translated version
```

I assume we can't use `next/router` `locale` out of the box, but that's acceptable as downside of the integration.

Comment: Try [i18next-browser-languagedetector](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector).